# File Select/File API - Sending files to Embedded PDFObject

Tags: javascript, file, select, fileapi, pdfobject

So I'm trying to use file select (or file API) to select file from desktop and send it to an embedded PDF viewer in my HTML Doc. I've tried a lot of different ways with my limited knowledge to push the file from the file-api to the PDFObject and nothing seems to work. I'm not sure if it's not able to do this or if I'm just doing it wrong in many different ways.

```
    <head>
    <link href="http://pdfobject.com/css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pdfobject.com/scripts/pdfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function (){
            var myPDF = new PDFObject(handleFileSelect).embed(); 
// ORIGINALLY var myPDF = new PDFObject({ URL: "location" }).embed();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pdf">It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser. <a href="/pdf/sample.pdf">Click here to download the PDF</a></div>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <output id="list"></output>

    <script>
      function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                      '</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
      }

      document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
```

Can I use file select/file api to select and push a document to the PDFObject viewer or does it not allow that sort of connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply retrieve the url of the file by creating one:

```
url=window.URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);
```

and then embed the file by giving PDFObject this url:

```
PDFObject.embed(url, "#fileContainer");
```